# Can I reenter UK on a Standard Visitor Visa granted for a job interview

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, interview

I applied for, and was granted a UK Standard Visitor Visa (MULT) valid from October 2019 to April 2020 (6 months validity)

This was for a job interview (Company A),I visited the UK in October and stayed for a week. I didn't get this job.

Now, I have a job interview at another company (Company B),
This company will also sponsor the flights, hotels and everything else

When I applied for my visa, I had mentioned the purpose as a job interview, and shared the visa invite letters from Company A.

Now I wish to reenter the UK (for 3 days),

1. Would I need to reapply for the visit visa, or can I use the existing visa (as it's multiple entry and valid for another 2 months)
2. Could the immigration officer at the airport have any questions, as to why I'm re-entering when the job interview (for company A) has already finished?
3. Can I tell them that this is for another job interview?
4. Would I need to carry invite letters from both company A & company B

Comment: 2-> Yes. 3->Yes, tell the truth so you have no holes in your answers.4-> For safety and to substantiate do carry them.